# Bogoliubov-de Gennes equation

Tags: symmetry, bose-einstein-condensate

Can we still assume translational invariance, and thus plane wave solutions, for the Bogoliubov-de Gennes equation for a trapped Bose-Einstein condensate (e.g., step or harmonic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If there is a potential you will have to use the eigenfunctions of the potential. You might like to look at our paper on BdG in a harmonic trap:

https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0702412

Beware however ---  there are two minus sign errors in this paper, but luckily they cancel each other.

Comment: But without using operators, starting from (7.42)-(7.43) in Pethik-Smoth book , which function can I best choose to work away the laplacian? Or for example, for a step potential what are the eigenfunctions?

Comment: You have to use the eigenfunctions of the Schroedinger equation. I don't know Stringari's book.

Comment: You have changed your question severakl times. Do you want GrossPitaevskii or BdG?

Comment: BdG but for Bose-Einstein condensates